# Fuel rail pressure low on common rail diesel

Tags: diesel, pressure

The engine can suddenly cut out when driving and either go into safe mode or stop altogether. Have changed pressure sensor, pressure regulator and fuel filter with no joy. Sometimes engine won't start from cold. OBD data shows rail pressure down at 1200 psi instead of 4600 psi when engine starts properly. Fuel pump must be working otherwise there would be no rail pressure at all. Any clues. Could this be a sticking injector given this is recycle system on my Kia?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What vehicle are we talking about here?

Comment: Just because the pump is working doesn't mean it can raise and maintain sufficient pressure. And of course the fault could be elsewhere in the system as well.

Comment: Hi, the car is a 2007 Kia Sorento CRD 2.5 diesel. Thx